# Error in Aurelia Template binding

Tags: aurelia

I think I might have a config issue. I am getting an error when looping over an array of objects. Here is the error. The array of objects are being loaded into the view and they look correct. Its just the "repeat.for" that blows up.

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: Incorrect syntax for "for". The form is: "$local of $items" or "[$key, $value] of $items".
at SyntaxInterpreter.for (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-binding@0.13.0/index.js:142:13)
at SyntaxInterpreter.interpret (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-binding@0.13.0/index.js:27:34)
at TemplatingBindingLanguage.createAttributeInstruction (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-binding@0.13.0/index.js:267:46)
at ViewCompiler.compileElement (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1442:41)
at ViewCompiler.compileNode (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1331:23)
at ViewCompiler.compileElement (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1536:31)
at ViewCompiler.compileNode (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1331:23)
at ViewCompiler.compileElement (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1536:31)
at ViewCompiler.compileNode (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1331:23)
at ViewCompiler.compileElement (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1536:31)
at ViewCompiler.compileNode (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1331:23)
at ViewCompiler.compileNode (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1353:33)
at ViewCompiler.compile (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1314:12)
at http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.13.2/index.js:1583:49
at run (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/es6.promise.js:91:43)
at http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/es6.promise.js:105:11
at module.exports (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.invoke.js:6:25)
at queue.(anonymous function) (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.task.js:40:9)
at Number.run (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.task.js:27:7)
at listner (http://localhost:8080/jspm_packages/npm/core-js@0.9.18/modules/$.task.js:31:9)
```

View

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Uploaded Date</th>
    <th>Bathrooms</th>
    <th>Bedrooms</th>
  </tr>
  <tr repeat.for="advert in adverts">
    <td>${advert.Id}</td>
    <td>${advert.DateAdded}</td>
    <td>${advert.Bathrooms}</td>
    <td>${advert.Bedrooms}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

ViewModel

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

export class App {
  constructor() {
  this.http = new HttpClient();
  this.adverts = [];
 }
 activate() {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost/BackEnd/api/adverts')
    .then(response => {
      this.adverts = response.content;
      console.log(this.adverts);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`repeat.for="advert in adverts"` needs to be `repeat.for="advert of adverts"`